# Authorization in ASP.NET for accessing a set of subdirectories depending on login

Tags: asp.net

Scenario: A web application consists of a root directory (open, no authorization) and a number of subdirectories (let's call them Sub1, Sub2 and Sub3). Furthermore, when an user name is provided, there's a method contacting a SP and returning an `IEnumerable<String>` consisting of the names of subdirectories, which that certain user is supposed to be allowed to access. The above is not changeable.

I wonder what the **neatest** way to solve this would be. I can't rely on AD and a simple authorization stored in a cookie or a session variable won't allow for a diversification of accessible subdirectories.

*I'm pretty confident I can make it work but I'd like to do it in bragable style.*

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it sounds like you could put a `web.config` in each of subfolders with

```
<authorization>
   <allow roles="SubfolderName" />
   <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

Then, for each user, attach the result of this `IEnumerable<string>` list of subfolders  to the user's roles in your role manager.

This way, each user trying to access the folder will have a proper role in his/her role list and the url authorization module will allow the user to access the folder.

Comment: Would it be possible to do that from the global web.config (e.g. through `<location path="SubDir1" />"`? I'm pretty sure i won't be allowed to put in local `web.config`s there. Also, would it e possible to programmatically either (1) add those lines to the global `web.config` or (2) create the local `web.config`s on the fly, so to speak?

Comment: Yes, you can create all these mappings in global `web.config`. Creating authorization rules on the fly is also possible, you just have to write your own http module and add a custom logic to the `AuthorizeRequest` method. Both approaches sound valid, the former seems easier as it depends on existing mechanisms.