# How can I delete a project without having access to the original project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

We have a multi-part web-based application.
 For each customer we have to remove part of it.
 How to manage the project in Visual Studio?
 Must be included when you install the program?
 Thank you to those who share his knowledge.

Comment: I dont really get what you are asking. Maybe you could give some more detail and tell us what you have tried so far.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove part of it"? Are you saying that there are ASPX documents that you deliver/don't deliver depending on whom you send it to? Or are we talking about a role set-up where, depending on the log-in and access rights, the client get different set of ASPX then can get to see?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I think I see what you're asking here. I'm guessing that you have a full scale solution constituted by, let's say three documents: `Water.apsx`, `Air.aspx`, `Land.aspx`. And the customers you're talking about are e.g. "Mr. Boat", "Mr. Helicopter" and "Mr. Airplane".

My assumption is that you'd like to develop a whole-coverage solution for all the types (that's the three ASPX files) but only deliver them according to the following schedule:

1. Mr. Boat -> Water.aspx
2. Mr. Helicopter -> Air.aspx
3. Mr. Airplane -> Air.aspx and Land.aspx (because planes can taxi on the ground)

If it's not correctly presumed, stop reading now!   :)

Otherwise:
You could deploy a solution based on roles. You'd assign a role (or, in fact a set of roles) to a visiting user of your site. Then, each page you've developed in the entire-register solution would be marked by a number of roles that it's visible to.

When the said user logs in, the set of roles assigned to that particular account would be constitute an access right table that can be used to permitting/stopping him from seeing certain pages.

I asked a very similar question (assuming that I've guessed your intentions correctly) a few weeks ago and [here's the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922364/authorization-in-asp-net-for-accessing-a-set-of-subdirectories-depending-on-logi) I've got.

Comment: hello, i have usercontrol base project.we load usercontrol via ajax and manualy render it.

Answer (score 0):

Here whjat I get is that youw ant that whenever a new member is accessing your application then they must get the UI based on the role, they are assigned.
Well in this regard an article based on [Roles and Membership](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/342061/Understanding-ASP-NET-Roles-and-Membership-A-Begin) may help.